# How to encrypt a file using my GPG private key so I can decrypt it later

Tags: gnupg, public-key-encryption

I have a text file on my GNU/Linux laptop and I want to encrypt it with my GPG private key so I can decrypt it later and see the output. I've tried this:

```
gpg --encrypt file.txt
```

but I'm asked to provide `Current recipients`. I don't want any recipients, I want to read it myself.

How can I encrypt a file using GPG?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used this method to encrypt a file `gpg -r your.email@example.com -e ./filename` and this will create filename.gpg which is the encrypted content.

And to decrypt you do `gpg -d filename.gpg`

In regards to the email requirement - when you generate a new key using `gpg --gen-key` you will be required to enter an email address and it will create a public/privatey key pair based on that email address. You simply need to use that same email address. It does not send it, it simply tell gpg which private/public key pair to use (and the identifier is the email address)

Comment: But this will encrypt file with public key. Then it will decrypt with private key. How can I encrypt with private so somebody with my public can decrypt it?

Answer (score 3):

A better way is to ***encrypt*** using your **PUBLIC** key, then use your **PRIVATE** key later to ***decrypt*** the file.  This way lends itself to automating encryption via a non-interactive script:

```
gpg --batch --yes --trust-model always -r $YOURGPGPUBKEYEMAIL -e ./file.txt
```

**NOTE**: I upload **ONLY** my **PUBLIC** key to public server I want to protect data on, keeping my **PRIVATE** key apart from it. That's pretty tight.

Obviously if you're **NOT** using your own public key, tread carefully with the `--trust-model always` switch.

Also be aware that decrypting will of course require a password unless you automate this too.  HTH- Terrence Houlahan

Comment: I think it's the same as accepted answer.

Comment: The accepted answer implies both public and private keys are on the same host. My answer proposes uploading *ONLY* your **PUBLIC** key to the host encrypting the data.  Without the `--trust-model always` switch I add to the command, an error will be puked about trust and break non-interactive automation.  So the approaches are technically very different.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way is to use `--encrypt-to name` with your id (typical: mail address) for `name`. [Documentation](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Key-related-Options.html) says that's the way to to "encrypt-to-self".

Comment: ...may be used with your own user-id as an "encrypt-to-self"... does in my book not indicate that it is a canonical way to do something. What are the advantages and disadvantages of using `--encrypt-to name` over `--recipient`?

Comment: @ini I guess I'm inclined to refer to that option as canonical because it's suggested to use it for "encrypt to self" in the official documentation at gnupg.org, see my link. In any case, `--recipient` will not be sufficient, you would have to add `--encrypt` (it's not optional). Classification of differences in behavior in "advantages" and "disadvantages" will depend on your use case and would be probably be opinion-based.